# Cython bug with vector and bint

Tags: cython

I found some undesired behaviour while using the C++ vector class. A specific inclusion of a `bint` variable causes other `int`s to become `bint`s.

This code

```
%%cython -a --cplus
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
print(<vector[int]>range(10))
```

outputs
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
which is expected.

But this code

```
%%cython -a --cplus
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef vector[bint] foobar = []
print(<vector[int]>range(10))
```

outputs
`[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`
which is very unexpected

I think something is wrong here.

Comment: Could you report it on the Cython issue tracker https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/?